# How to enable finger printer with Thinkpad X230

Tags: thinkpad, fingerprint-reader

I am a newbie with Ubuntu and  Linux, and I just switched from Windows 8. I have installed 12.04 on my new Lenovo Thinkpad x230. It seems everything else works perfectly except the finger printer. I have been using Finger Printer for a long time, and I really rely it on  for my Lastpass application. But I don't know how to enable or install the driver of the finger printer. Can anybody help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the answer below doesn't work out, please paste the results of the command "lsusb" so we can see exactly what hardware we are dealing with.  Chris

Answer (score 16):

### For 13.04 and newer

For the X220/X230:

```
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install libpam-fprintd libfprint0 fprint-demo fprintd
```

Then run this command to configure pam:

```
sudo pam-auth-update
```

Finally enroll your finger with:

```
fprintd-enroll
```

Comment: This answer works on 14.10.

Answer (score 5):

### For 12.04

I have a X220 Thinkpad and I use `fprint` and it works well!

Add the PPA to get the latest version:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fingerprint/fprint
```

And install `fprint`:

```
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install libpam-fprint libfprint0 fprint-demo gksu-polkit fprintd
```

Then run this command to configure `pam`:

```
sudo pam-auth-update
```

Finnaly enroll your finger with:

```
fprintd-enroll
```

### For Ubuntu 12.04 at ThinkPad X230

According to https://launchpad.net/~fingerprint/+archive/fprint

1. Add this PPA to your sources:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fingerprint/fprint
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get upgrade
   ```
2. Install the software:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libfprint0 fprint-demo libpam-fprintd gksu-polkit
   ```
3. Update authentication methods:

   ```
   sudo pam-auth-update
   ```
4. Enroll your finger:

   ```
   sudo pam_fprint_enroll
   ```

Then it have started working for me.

Answer (score 2):

The X230 has an "upgraded" fingerprint sensor with an onboard co-processor.  Its the 147e:2020.  As of right now, it appears to be unsupported.

Comment: It is now supported.  Please see below.

Answer (score 2):

The fprint library has been upgraded to support the X230 finger print reader!
Get it here: https://launchpad.net/~fingerprint/+archive/fprint

(Typed on an X230 with working finger print reader!)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe worth mentioning: for logging on using your fingerprint reader you might want to install the *Fingerprint GUI* application as mentioned at [LaunchPad](https://launchpad.net/~fingerprint/+archive/ubuntu/fingerprint-gui).